# qsort unexpectedly working while using "a > b" as comparator

Tags: c, qsort

I came across a qsort comparator function that was incorrectly using "a > b" as the comparison operation. I would expect this code to just somewhat randomly reorder the array, but it was working on my school's instructional servers (Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS). It didn't work on my own laptop as expected, so I'm not sure what could be causing this bug.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void print_arr(int* arr, size_t n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

int int_compar(const void *x, const void *y)
{
  int i_x = *((int*)x);
  int i_y = *((int*)y);
  return i_x > i_y;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n = (1<<4);
  int in[n];

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    in[i] = rand() % 100;

  printf("Before: ");
  print_arr(in, n);

  qsort(in, n, sizeof(int), int_compar);

  printf("After: ");
  print_arr(in, n);

  return 0;
}
```

My laptop:

```
$ ./qsort_test
Before: 7 49 73 58 30 72 44 78 23 9 40 65 92 42 87 3
After: 23 7 9 3 58 44 42 40 49 30 65 72 73 78 87 92
```

Ubuntu:

```
$ ./qsort_test
Before: 83 86 77 15 93 35 86 92 49 21 62 27 90 59 63 26
After: 15 21 26 27 35 49 59 62 63 77 83 86 86 90 92 93
```

Comment: It "works" by sheer luck; there's clearly some detail of that specific `qsort` implementation that happens to produce the correct result for that particular input set with that particular (broken) comparator.

Comment: Ubuntu `qsort()` evidently does the same thing when the `fcmp()` return value is `< 0` or `0`.  OP's `qsort()` takes a different path, maybe does the same on `> 0` or `0`.

Comment: The usual [implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/msort.c;h=02ef28b89d9e1be5caa1b605b61d25bbfdfd9a3c;hb=HEAD#l65) of qsort in glibc only cares whether the comparator is <= 0.  But if it falls back on [quicksort](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/qsort.c;h=04c25b984f74a8f738233cc6da8a738b6437833c;hb=HEAD#l122), it cares whether it's < 0 instead, which won't work with your comparator.

Comment: @Tavian Barnes yes, it's unlikely to be sheer luck that it works. Perhaps the sort implementation that works, unnecessarily swaps values that are considered equal, which will then work for the case `i_x < i_y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the contract for using `qsort`, thus invoking [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984).
Specifically, your comparison-function is bad:

> #### 7.22.5.2 The qsort function
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
> int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
> ```
>
> Description
>   2 The `qsort` function sorts an array of `nmemb` objects, the initial element of which is
>   pointed to by `base`. The size of each object is specified by `size`.
>   3 The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison
>   function pointed to by `compar`, which is called with two arguments that point to the
>   objects being compared. **The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to,
>   or greater than the second.**
>   4 If two elements compare as equal, their order in the resulting sorted array is unspecified.
>   Returns
>   5 The `qsort` function returns no value.

It should be more along the lines of:

```
int int_compar(const void *x, const void *y)
{
  int i_x = *(int*)x;
  int i_y = *(int*)y;
  return i_x > i_y - i_x < i_y;
}
```

Now, the comparison-function is partially functional instead of completely broken, it **does indicate whether the first is bigger than the second**, but **does not differentiate between them being equal or the second being bigger**.
Depending on how the algorithm happens to be written, that might make the algorithm see all as equal, not react to your error at all, or do something funny.
For an example, all C++ standard-library sorting algorithms are written to only use less-than for comparison.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is "why does it seem to work on a particular machine?".

Comment: The fact that the OP is *well aware* that the implementation is wrong. What he's interested in is why it works on his school's Ubuntu boxes, not why it doesn't work on his laptop.

Comment: @PhilipKendall It does not work. It **appears to be working,** which is a rather unfortunate, but totally expected, outcome of undefined behavior.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant And your comment should be the answer, not just repeating a fact the OP already knows (that it's wrong), even with more detail.

Comment: Is there really a need for `return i_x > i_y - i_x < i_y;` and not `return i_x - i_y;`? The return value can be any, not just `-1 <= retval <= 1`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Thanks, added a bit more, but he was asking what was causing the bug, not why it seems to work at school.

Comment: @Weather Vane `ix - iy` suffers from `int` overflow.  Consider `INT_MAX - (-1)`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks, that last paragraph is exactly what I was looking for. But if all C++ algorithms are written to only use less-than for comparisons, shouldn't I expect the same behavior across different OS? If I'm thinking about this correctly, my results seem to indicate that the Linux stdlib is only using > operations, because it is working while only returning the correct result for > comparisons.

Comment: @alotofdavid: But that's the C++ standard-library, not the C standard library which is included in it. Anyway, good thinking, really looks like C `qsort` is implemented independently of C++ `std::sort`, at least for Linux.